# icheck will POST when box is checked but not when unchecked

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to use [icheck](http://icheck.fronteed.com/) to POST to a file for a temporary table and then uncheck it to remove the entry from the table. Right now when I check the box, it does alert me and store the information into the database. Whenever I uncheck it, nothing seems to happen. Even putting alert messages before the if statement is not being triggered.

Checkbox

```
<td><input type="checkbox" class="check" value="76624148" ></td>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input').on('ifChecked', function(event){
    var checked = $(this).is(":checked");
    if(checked){
        var value = $(this).val();
        $.post('functions/jQuery/search/checkBox.php', { value:value }, function(data){
            // data = 0 - means that there was an error
            // data = 1 - means that everything is ok
            if(data == 1){
                // Do something or do nothing :-)
                alert('Data was saved in db!');
            } 
        });
    } else {
        var value = $(this).val();
        $.post('functions/jQuery/search/uncheckBox.php', { value:value }, function(data){
            // data = 0 - means that there was an error
            // data = 1 - means that everything is ok
            if(data == 1){
                // Do something or do nothing :-)
                alert('Data was removed in db!');
            }
        });
    }
    });

});
```

Comment: try using `$('input').on('ifChanged',function(){})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the following worked for me

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input').on('ifChecked', function(event){
        var value = $(this).val();
        $.post('functions/jQuery/search/checkBox.php', { value:value }, function(data){
            // data = 0 - means that there was an error
            // data = 1 - means that everything is ok
            if(data == 1){
                // Do something or do nothing :-)
                alert('Data was saved in db!');
            } 
        });
    });

    $('input').on('ifUnchecked', function(event){
        var value = $(this).val();
        $.post('functions/jQuery/search/uncheckBox.php', { value:value }, function(data){
            // data = 0 - means that there was an error
            // data = 1 - means that everything is ok
            if(data == 1){
                // Do something or do nothing :-)
                alert('Data was removed in db!');
            }
        });
    });
});
```